# How to send data from exacttarget to sfdc using v5 connector

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I am using v5 connector to integrate salesforce and exacttarget.
How can I send exacttarget data back to salesforce.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What kind of data are we talking about? Reporting data on email sends will automatically be sent back to Salesforce anytime you send an email to a Salesforce Report or Campaign. Unsubscribes and Profile Centers (assuming you are using the default) are configured to automatically update fields in Salesforce too.

If you are looking for a two-way synchronization of data, that unfortunately doesn't really exist. There is the ability to import objects from Salesforce into the Marketing Cloud, either through an Import Interaction or the new Data Stream features in Contact Builder, but the communication form those is strictly one-way (Salesforce into Marketing Cloud).

If you wanted to move subscriber information back to Salesforce you would have to do an export to your FTP, and then re-upload in Salesforce. This process can be automated in Automation Studio.

Hope that helps!